# How to re-create or update schema on Postgresql Foreign Data Wrappers?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-data

I had two postgresql database server, each running on separate physical server. One is running version 13.3 (say server A) and the other 9.6 (say server B).

I have installed postgresql's foreign data wrapper on server A connected to sever B, and imported schema from server B (say b_adempiere).

As I work with server B (add/delete field inside view), Today I noticed that the view inside imported schema on server A, doesn't get updated with schema on server B. I have to delete imported schema on server A, and re-import schema from server B.

```
DROP SCHEMA b_adempiere CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA b_adempiere;
IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA adempiere FROM SERVER b_server INTO b_adempiere;
```

Question: How to automatically re-create/update imported schema on server A, each time we make structure database update on server B ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do this automatically. Either make sure you also `ALTER` the foreign table whenever you `ALTER` the underlying table or view, or regularly drop and re-import the foreign tables.